# ANTLR : How to replace all characters defined as space with actual space

Tags: antlr, antlr3

My ANTLR code is as follow :

```
LPARENTHESIS : ('('); 
RPARENTHESIS : (')'); 

fragment CHARACTER : ('a'..'z'|'0'..'9'|); 
fragment QUOTE     : ('"'); 
fragment WILDCARD  : ('*'); 
fragment SPACE     : (' '|'\n'|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|';'|':'|','); 

WILD_STRING 
   : (CHARACTER)* 
     ( 
       ('?') 
       (CHARACTER)* 
     )+ 
   ; 
PREFIX_STRING 
   : (CHARACTER)+
     ( 
       ('*')  
     )+ 
   ; 
WS     : (SPACE) { $channel=HIDDEN; }; 
PHRASE : (QUOTE)(LPARENTHESIS)?(WORD)(WILDCARD)?(RPARENTHESIS)?((SPACE)+(LPARENTHESIS)?(WORD)(WILDCARD)?(RPARENTHESIS)?)*(SPACE)+(QUOTE); 
WORD   : (CHARACTER)+;
```

What I would like to do is to replace all characters marked as space to be replaced with actual space character in the PHRASE. Also if possible, I would then like all continuous spaces to be represented by a single space.

Any help would be most appreciated. For some reason, I am finding it hard to understand ANTLR. Any good tutorials out there ?

Answer (score 3):

### Java

Invoke your [lexer's `setText(...)` method](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_lexer.html#8565bcfe79732c7e6770da4e90757160):

```
grammar T;

parse
  :  words EOF {System.out.println($words.text);}
  ;

words    
  :  Word (Spaces Word)* 
  ;

Word  
  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+
  ;

Spaces
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {setText(" ");}
  ;
```

Which can be tested with the class:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String source = "This         is     \n    just \t\t\t\t\t\t a \n\t\t test";
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(source);
        TLexer lexer = new TLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);
        System.out.println("------------------------------\nSource:\n" + source +
                "\n------------------------------\nAfter parsing:");
        parser.parse();
    }
}
```

which produces the following output:

```
------------------------------
Source:
This         is     
    just                         a 
         test
------------------------------
After parsing:
This is just a test
```

> ***Puneet Pawaia** wrote:*
>
> Any help would be most appreciated. For some reason, I am finding it hard to understand ANTLR. Any good tutorials out there ?

The [ANTLR Wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+3+Wiki+Home) has loads of informative info, albeit a bit unstructured (but that could just be me!).

The best ANTLR tutorial is the book: [The Definitive ANTLR Reference: Building Domain-Specific Languages](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference).

### C#

For the C# target, try this:

```
grammar T;

options {
  language=CSharp2;
}

@parser::namespace { Demo }
@lexer::namespace { Demo }

parse
  :  words EOF {Console.WriteLine($words.text);}
  ;

words    
  :  Word (Spaces Word)* 
  ;

Word  
  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+
  ;

Spaces
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {Text = " ";}
  ;
```

with the test class:

```
using System;
using Antlr.Runtime;

namespace Demo
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            ANTLRStringStream Input = new ANTLRStringStream("This         is     \n    just \t\t\t\t\t\t a \n\t\t test"); 
            TLexer Lexer = new TLexer(Input);
            CommonTokenStream Tokens = new CommonTokenStream(Lexer);
            TParser Parser = new TParser(Tokens);
            Parser.parse();
        }
    }
}
```

which also prints `This is just a test` to the console. I tried to use `SetText(...)` instead of `setText(...)` but that didn't work either, and the [C# API docs](http://www.antlr.org/api/CSharp/index.html) are currently off-line, so I used the trial and error-hack `{Text = " ";}`. I tested it with the [C# 3.1.1 runtime DLL's](http://www.antlr.org/download/CSharp/DOT-NET-runtime-3.1.1.zip).

Good luck!

Comment: Bart again to the rescue. However, I am unable to get this to replace things in my PHRASE. I am also working on C# if that has any relevance.

Comment: I am using AntlrWorks 1.4 to test this code  in my grammer as I am unable to compile the code generated by later versions with C# libraries.

Comment: Bart, I tried this Text = " " thing earlier also but for some reason, I am ending up with all the text gone. So my code just ends up returning a space and nothing else.

Comment: @Puneet, thwn I don't know what else to tell you. It works on my machine with the code I posted and the DLL's I linked to. Since I am fairly unfamiliar with C#, I don't know what else to suggest. Good luck.